# PrimeFaces dynamic menu: Cannot remove the same component twice and ID generation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:menu>` in a `<p:dataTable>` for which we are getting irregular `FacesException`s when upgrading to Mojarra 2.1.22 (on GlassFish 3.1.2.2):

```
        <p:dataTable id="data"
                     widgetVar="resultDataTable" 
                     value="#{depotManager.dataModel}"
                     var="dep"
                     rowKey="#{dep.id}"
                     selection="#{depotManager.selectedEntities}"
                     selectionMode="#{depotManager.singleSelectionMode ? 'single' : 'multiple'}"
                     ...
                     emptyMessage="#{msg['entity.depot.list.emptyMessage']}">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"...

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGroup id="header"
                              layout="block">

                    <p:menu overlay="true"
                            trigger="sub-client-button"
                            my="left top"
                            at="left bottom"
                            model="#{accountManagerMenuKeeper.subClientMenuModel}" />
```

The exception we get is:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot remove the same component twice: content-form:data:menu-item-1
```

Similar problem is here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23669

I did some investigation, the problem seems to be that we're using view-scoped beans with PrimeFaces 3.5.28. I switched the menu bean to request-scoped, as described here:

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2594

We're not able to switch to PrimeFaces 4... some of the Exceptions went away, but not all (maybe half of them). So the problem remains.

Understanding the problem a little better now with unique ID generation, reading https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2283 , I probably need to generate IDs underneath the dataTable naming container.

The ID for the dataTable is "content-form:data", so I suppose I need to generate unique IDs for each dynamic menu item, which I am currently not doing I think (one menu item per client, simple counter appended):

```
        for ( Client subClient : subClients )
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.setId( "menu-item-" + ( ++i ) );
//            item.setId( "content-form:data:menu-item-" + ( ++i ) );
            ...
        }
```

*Q:*

How do you generate correct ID's here, e.g. using the inbuilt means of JSF like createUniqueId() etc.?

It's a little strang to me, as the exception mentions the full ID with the dataTable's ID in front: `javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot remove the same component twice: content-form:data:menu-item-1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away even on PrimeFaces 3.5.28 using simple request-scoped, menu-creation beans:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AccountManagerMenuKeeper implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    @SeamLogger
    protected Logger          log;

    @Inject
    protected SessionHelper   sessionHelper;

    @Inject
    private DepotManager      accountManager;

    private MenuModel         subClientMenuModel;

    /**
     * @return the subClientMenuModel
     */
    public MenuModel getSubClientMenuModel()
    {
        if ( this.subClientMenuModel == null )
        {
            buildSubClientMenuModel();
        }

        return ( this.subClientMenuModel );
    }

    /**
     * Builds the menu model for adding sub-clients.
     * 
     */
    private void buildSubClientMenuModel()
    {
        this.subClientMenuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
        List<Client> subClients = this.accountManager.getWritableSubClients();

        if ( subClients == null || subClients.isEmpty() )
            return;

        // Necessary instances
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
        Application application = facesContext.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory factory = application.getExpressionFactory();

        int i = 0;

        for ( Client subClient : subClients )
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.setId( "menu-item-" + ( ++i ) );

            item.setValue( subClient.getName() );
            item.setProcess( "@this" );
            item.setUpdate( ":content-form" );
            item.setDisabled( this.accountManager.isReadOnly() || !this.accountManager.isSingleSelectionMode() || EMode.ADD.equals( this.accountManager.getMode() ) || EMode.EDIT.equals( this.accountManager.getMode() ) );
            item.setActionExpression( factory.createMethodExpression( elContext, "#{depotManager.add}", String.class, new Class[] {} ) );

            ValueExpression targetExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "#{depotManager.selectedSubClientId}", Long.class );
            ValueExpression valueExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "" + subClient.getId(), Long.class );
            item.addActionListener( new SwitchableSetPropertyActionListener( targetExpression, valueExpression ) );

            this.subClientMenuModel.addMenuItem( item );
        }
    }
}
```

This will/should work with newer Mojarra versions. (DUH)